# Django manytomany field shows all existing objects of that type in the admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The title covers most of it. I have a model Game with a manytomany field called users this field has blank=True because it can be empty. Whenever I open this object in the admin it shows a list of all existing users instead of the users that are added to this particular game object. If i print the users in my consumer it shows that it is empty (which it is). How can I make the admin show the user objects that are in the users field.

Comment: How is this rendered. In a form, to edit the record, it will show all `User`s, such that you can *select* which users to add.